# System.IO.IOException error, can't get access to the file

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, file-access

I can't understand where problem is, despite the fact, that this code pretty easy.

I have such function:

```
public void WriteToDoc(string path)    
{
     XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("General parameters",
                                   new XElement("num_path", num_path.Text),
                                   new XElement("Gen_Peroid", Gen_Peroid.Text),
                                   new XElement("Alg_Perioad", Alg_Perioad.Text))
                                  );
     doc.Save(path); // here he gives that exception
}
```

`num_path.Text`, `Gen_Peroid.Text` and `Alg_Perioad.Text` are `string`.

This is how I use this function:

```
File.Create(@"C:\ProgramData\RadiolocationQ\Q.xml");
WriteToDoc(@"C:\ProgramData\RadiolocationQ\Q.xml");
```

It creates file, but nothing was written in that file.  So the exact error `System.IO.IOException` error, The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. How is it possible to get such error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers state, you are not closing your output file. The proper way of saving XML files using LinqToXML is:

```
System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xws = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
xws.Indent = true;
xws.IndentChars = "\t";

FileStream fsConfig = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
using (System.Xml.XmlWriter xw = System.Xml.XmlWriter.Create(fsConfig, xws))
{
       doc.Save(xw);
}
fsConfig.Close();
```

This releases the file & stream. You can omit the `XmlWriterSettings` if not needed.

Answer (score 2):

**You are the process that has it open!**

Don't call `File.Create` first - it leaves the file stream open, and you can't write over the file.

[`XDocument.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830.aspx) will create the file - you don't have to:

> Serialize this XDocument to a file, overwriting an existing file, if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
System.IO.File.Create(@"C:\ProgramData\RadiolocationQ\Q.xml").Close();
```

Edit: Reinhards answer is better. My is just closing the File.Create() stream, which locks the File, but there is no need for.

Answer (score 2):

[XDocument.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will create a file if one doesnt exist.  There is no need for `File.Create()`

`File.Create()` is not closing, It is locking the file on you.