# Can't remove all elements that share same attribute value in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I want to remove all elements that have the same name in one go. My current method removes one at a time even if I have more than one element with the same name.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\test.xml");
var course = new XElement("Course", 
                          new XAttribute("Name", cname),
                          new XAttribute("Code", ccode),
                          new XAttribute("Length", clenght));                
doc.Element("Departments").Element("Department1").Add(course);
doc.Save("D:\\test.xml");
```

This is my current remove code:
string sss  is the text a get from a textbox.

```
remove(string sss)

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("D:\\test.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> elList = 
    from el in doc.Descendants("Deparment1").Elements("Course")
    where el.Attribute("Name").Value == sss
    select el;

// this should filter elements with same name attribute value 
foreach (XElement el in elList)
{
    el.Remove();
    doc.Save("D:\\test.xml");
}
// this should remove them all and update the xml file
```

@Andrei V it doesn't change if I put the doc.save outside the foreach

Comment: Thought so. I read your post wrong... Did you inspect the selected elements to see if they're correctly selected? How about after the deletion? I personally don't think that the xml is correctly saved to file.

Comment: The elements are correctly selected, just checked  with a counter. It seems after it removes the first  element it exits the foreach.

Comment: Try to get the `Save` out of the `foreach` and save the document as described in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20370299/2474175).

Comment: It works now. I used ToList();

Comment: Ah... A simple break point inside the `foreach` would have saved you a lot of trouble...

Answer (score 0):

```
doc.Descendants("Deparment1").Elements("Course")
   .Where(el=>el.Attribute("Name").Value == sss)
   .Remove();
```